# Change a table element content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, element

I'm trying to modify the contents of  specific `<td>`'s unsuccessfully.
The idea is to change the script word `'S/JUROS'` to `' C/JUROS'` from `8x`.
Any suggestions for the best way to do this? I already managed to rescue the values ​​in an array, but got caught at this stage.

https://jsfiddle.net/diasbass/23swmsvn/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (jQuery(".tbl-payment-system").length) {

    var getTexts = [];
    $(".tbl-payment-system tr td.parcelas").each(function() {
      getTexts.push($(this).text())
    });

    var resultTexts = '"' + getTexts.join('", "') + '"';
    console.log(resultTexts);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" class="tbl-payment-system" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="parcelas">Nº de Parcelas</th>
      <th class="valor">Valor de cada parcela</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 600,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">2X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 300,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">3X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 200,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">4X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 150,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">5X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 120,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">6X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 100,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">7X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 85,71</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">8X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 81,87</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">9X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 73,47</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">10X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 66,76</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">11X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 64,81</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">12X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 60,24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/diasbass/23swmsvn/

Comment: Is requirement to change text only from `td` containing `8x` forwards?

Comment: Do you want to change the actual text of elements or only save changed text to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:contains()`, `.add()`, general sibling selector `~`, `.map()`, `.replace()`, `.get()`. Note, not clear if requirement is to change text of `html` `td` element or only text stored at array? If expected result is for `td` element text to be changed you can use `.text(function(index, originalText) {})` where new text is returned

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (jQuery(".tbl-payment-system").length) {

    var getTexts = [];
    var x = $(".tbl-payment-system tr:contains(8X)");
    var resultTexts = x.add($("~ tr", x)).map(function() {
     return $("td.parcelas", this).text(function(_, text) {
       return text.replace(/S(?=\/)/, "C")
       }).text()
    }).get();
    console.log('"' + resultTexts.join('", "') + '"');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" class="tbl-payment-system" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="parcelas">Nº de Parcelas</th>
      <th class="valor">Valor de cada parcela</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 600,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">2X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 300,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">3X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 200,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">4X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 150,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">5X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 120,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">6X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 100,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">7X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 85,71</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">8X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 81,87</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">9X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 73,47</td>
    </tr>https://jsfiddle.net/23swmsvn/3/

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">10X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 66,76</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">11X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 64,81</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">12X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 60,24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/23swmsvn/5/

Comment: Thanks guys. All solutions are great. They helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```js
 $("td").each(function(){
     if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 8){
       $(this).text(($(this).text()).replace("S/JUROS","C/JUROS"));
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" class="tbl-payment-system" style="display: table;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <th class="parcelas">Nº de Parcelas</th>
            <th class="valor">Valor de cada parcela</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="parcelas">X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   600,00</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="parcelas">2X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   300,00</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="parcelas">3X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   200,00</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="parcelas">4X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   150,00</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="parcelas">5X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   120,00</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="parcelas">6X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   100,00</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="parcelas">7X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   85,71</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="parcelas">8X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   81,87</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="parcelas">9X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   73,47</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="parcelas">10X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   66,76</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="parcelas">11X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   64,81</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="parcelas">12X S/JUROS</td>
            <td>R$   60,24</td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. All solutions are great. They helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Find 8X using `:contains`, then go it its `parent` and `nextUntil` the end. Then `addBack` to include 8X and get each rows `:first-child`.

Then `each` over them to update the text:-

```js
var elements = $('table td:contains(8X)').parent().nextUntil().addBack().children(':first-child');

elements.each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace('S/JUROS', 'C/JUROS'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" class="tbl-payment-system" style="display: table;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="parcelas">Nº de Parcelas</th>
      <th class="valor">Valor de cada parcela</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 600,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">2X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 300,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">3X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 200,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">4X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 150,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">5X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 120,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">6X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 100,00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">7X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 85,71</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">8X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 81,87</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">9X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 73,47</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">10X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 66,76</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td class="parcelas">11X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 64,81</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="parcelas">12X S/JUROS</td>
      <td>R$ 60,24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. All solutions are great. They helped a lot!